# How do I make big jungle trees?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found a jungle biome in my new Minecraft world, but I'm afraid of cutting down the big trees (the ones that are 2 squares wide and long), because I don't know if I can replant them.

So is it possible to grow new ones with saplings or to spawn them in any other way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Planting a single jungle sapling will create on of the small jungle trees.

[image: A single jungle sapling][image: A small jungle tree]

Placing a group of 4 jungle saplings in a square (and using bonemeal) will make a large jungle tree. I'm not sure if the bone meal is required, or just speeds it up.

[image: 4 jungle saplings][image: A large jungle tree]

<s>Apparently not all the saplings need to be jungle saplings, just the one you use bone meal on.</s>
*This was patched in MineCraft 1.2.4, and no longer works; all 4 saplings need to be jungle saplings.*

[image: Mixed group of saplings][image: It still creates a large tree]

Comment: Confirmed in creative that this does work, kewl! :)

Comment: It is not required to use bonemeal to grow the tree.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, there is another way to create an arbitrarily tall skinny tree:

1. From the ground, create one block tower of wood from the tree that you are trying to grow (for example, birch wood for a birch sapling).
2. When you've reached the approximate desired height of your tree, place a block of dirt atop your tower.
3. Place the sapling in the dirt.
4. Apply bonemeal to the sapling.
5. Replace the dirt block with a wood block.

Ta da!  You've created the equivalent of a [truffula tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lorax)!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, big trees are random but any sapling can be forced to (eventually) create a big tree:

> If a sapling is surrounded by a 2 block tall tube it guarantees that it will, eventually, grow into a big tree. The tube forces the small tree growth to always fail each attempt. However, this takes far longer to produce a mature tree, due to the low chance that a sapling will try to grow into a big tree.

From [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tree).

Although remember that trees are just generated structures. You can harvest leaves with [shears](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Shears) and make your own giant trees!

Comment: This description on the Wiki was written for the classic "oak"/"apple" trees, not jungle trees (it also does not apply to birch/pine trees). This should not be assumed to be the case for jungle trees until someone has done the experiment.

Comment: @KevinReid I just confirmed (in MineCraft: Xbox One edition) that this trick (surrounding the sapplings with a 2 block tall tube, making sure to leave a single block of space between the wall and the sapplings) works.

Answer (score -2):

If you want a big jungle tree in a non-jungle habitat then here what to do:

1. Dig a one block deep hole.
2. Place one piece of sand in the hole.
3. Then place one piece of dirt on top.
4. Last but not least put a the jungle sapling on top of it all and use bone-meal on it.