# What is the tallest trees can grow in the Jungle Biome?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Between what heights will "Jungle" biome trees grow to?  I'm curious because sometimes I get really short awkward trees, and at times I get huge trees with multiple layers of leaves.  Is there a minimum height or maximum height?

Comment: Maybe this question/answer will help? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52938/how-do-i-make-big-trees

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  I know how to grow jungle trees, but the heights in which they grow are often random....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia there is no real limit found in the code with regard to the height cap. There is however a limit found in the number of logs of which a tree may exist of: 55.

Comment: Wikipedia, or the Minecraft Wiki?

Comment: so the max height of a jungle tree (2x2 saplings) is 13?

Answer (score 1):

I've grown ones that are 31 in height, from ground to the top of their leaves. I doubt that's a maximum though.

As for a minimum, you could get at that by trying to grow trees under platforms of different heights.